# Problem changing date of birth on a PS4

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

I want to add the correct date of birth for my 11-year old son on his PlayStation account but it won't let me, only allowing me to put an age of 16+ while he's 11.

I find the online agent help support very poor and it kicks me out after waiting. Is there an email for their help desk? I have even uploaded my son's passport to the age verification and even this doesn't then change his age to his actual.

My son used a date of birth to make him 18 without my knowledge, and I don't seem to be able to change it now. I want to add him to my family management to control his game time.

Answer (score 1):

[Appar](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/lck9kg/how_do_i_change_dob_in_child_account/)[ently](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/i0dqbr/any_way_to_change_a_child_psn_account_birthday/), you shouldn't be able to change the date of birth on accounts.
However:

- One solution is to create a new account for your son (an account naturally 'matures' with a user, changing its account type automatically).
- Another, more useful one, is to change it by linking your current Sony account to another Sony account through [sonymobile.com](https://account.sonymobile.com/#/signin):

  > The only way you can change your age on a Sony account that already exists is to use it to connect to the Sony Mobile service. When you connect to this part of Sony’s network with your pre-existing PlayStation account, it asks for your date of birth as part of the registration process.

  The steps to take, as per [this site](https://www.alphr.com/change-age-ps4/):

  > - Go to [sonymobile.com](https://account.sonymobile.com/#/signin).
  > - In the text box labeled E-mail address, enter the address you use to log in to the PlayStation account that you want to change the age for.
  >   [image]
  > - Click on the blue Sign in button.
  > - When the next page loads, enter your password into the Password text box and click on the blue Sign In button.
  > - Now, Sony will ask you to confirm your birth date. It is vital that you input the date you want for the life of your account here. Once you click the ‘Next’ button, there’s no going back. Even refreshing the browser or logging in again will not take you back to this page.
  > - Scroll down to where it says Date of birth, and use the drop-down menus to enter the date of birth that you want to use from now on.
  >   [image]
  > - Click on the box to confirm that you have read the privacy statement.
  > - Click on the blue Save button.
  > - Again, we can’t stress this enough, this is the one and only way currently available for you to ever change the age connected to your PlayStation account. If you get it wrong this time, you’re basically out of luck unless Sony finally decides to make everyone’s life a little bit easier.

  Just to make sure, this information is backup by [this](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-change-your-age-playstation-4), [this](https://thedroidguy.com/change-age-on-ps4-2021-1146914), and [this](https://www.technewstoday.com/change-age-ps4-ps5/) site. Please let me know if it works, because I can't verify it. Good luck!